# influxdb python OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t

Tags: python, influxdb

Good news, everyone!

Today I'll be delivering an error to the stack overflow community, that i really didnt fix or find any solution by myself. and this is my first question here.
i am working with an influxdb v1.8 and using the python module influxdb, to get the data and work with it in python.

There is data with timestamps in the 1950s until today stored in the database. but I can only get data using query time conditions like

```
"select * from \"my_measurement\" where \"time\" >= '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'"
```

if i want data before 1970 the following error msg occurred:

`OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t`
the error msg was raised by:
`timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_s)`

At [InfluxDB frequently asked questions](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#what-are-the-minimum-and-maximum-timestamps-that-influxdb-can-store) is the minimum timestamp at `1677-09-21T00:12:43.145224194Z`, which makes sense because the data exists and I can visualize the data using Grafana. i also tried the query string from Grafana which looks something like this

```
q='SELECT * FROM "my_measurement" WHERE time >= -1243409701000ms and time <= 1627595446000ms GROUP BY time(30d) fill(null)'
```

and guess what, the same error.

here is some explicit code:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
client = InfluxDBClient(ip, port, user_name, pw, db_name) 
q = 'SELECT * FROM "air_temperature_01h_dwd_historical" WHERE "STATIONS_ID"=$STATIONS_ID AND "station_name"=$station_name AND "type"=$type AND "time" >= \'1950-01-01T00:00:00Z\' AND "time" < \'1960-01-01T00:00:00Z\''  
bind_params = {'STATIONS_ID': '1303', 'station_name': 'Essen-Bredeney', 'type': '01h'}
p = client.query(q, bind_params=bind_params).get_points() # crash
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-112-edd8923b846b>", line 1, in <module>
    p = client.query(q, bind_params=bind_params).get_points()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py", line 521, in query
    response = self.request(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py", line 358, in request
    response._msgpack = msgpack.unpackb(

  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 195, in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py", line 1248, in _msgpack_parse_hook
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_s)

OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

if i leave out the time parameter, the error occurs also, as well as do not using bind_params by concatting the query string with the parameters.

please, someone out there, help! push me in the chamber of understanding

Comment: provide your full python code ,  your sql code looks ok (for data before 1970 ) by reversing the condition in your first example

Comment: add it in the post above

Comment: Please show us the entire traceback.  It's true that `utcfromtimestamp` can only handle dates from 1970 to 2036, but I don't see that line of code in the influxdb module.

Comment: edit the traceback above